# Lock screen is not changing after updating to Android 4.4.2

Tags: updates, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-grand, background-process

I have updated my Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 to 4.4.2 and after that I'm not able to change my lock screen wallpaper. It always shows a wallpaper which is already in the device which has red background. Home screen changes every time whenever I want to change but lock screen remains the same. But if I put a live wallpaper as my home and lock screen it applies to both home and lock screen. Please suggest something how I would be able to put any pic from my gallery as lock screen. I changed the lock screen through settings also but no use.

Answer (score 1):

I have a HISENSE SERO7 e2371 tablet here. I could not get the lock screen wallpaper to change at all.

Finally figured it out and thought I would post it here just in case anyone is looking for a solution.

I went into **Settings → Security → Screen Lock** and changed  **Hisense** to **Slide**.

It seems that it was an issue with the Hisense custom lock screen they provided, so this may be  same on other devices where the manufacturer has added a custom lock screen option.

Answer (score -2):

just a quick search results show me that you may try power off and removing the battery some people face the same issue after update

Answer (score -2):

Just change unlock effect.. 
There you go.. You can change lock screen wallpaper on Grand 2.
Setting-device-lock screen - unlock effect. Change it. 
Thank you

Comment: OP already stated: *I changed the lock screen through settings also but no use* – so how is your answer different?

Answer (score -4):

I think it is software glitch on the Grand 2. To solve the problem, try to transfer the SIM 2 to 1. You may be able to change the lockscreen wallpaper.

Comment: Try to transfer the SIM to what? Why would that affect the lock screen?